# Hard drive not recognized after install

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, encryption

I have a Dell Laptop (Vostro 3500) and tried to install Ubuntu 14.10 64bit on it.
It came with Windows 7 installed on it.

So I try the install from a live CD, I select both full disk encryption and home folder encryption in the install options.
At the end it says my install has failed for some reason, I try to reinstall by formatting the drive (data recovery isn't necessary) but it doesn't find it anymore.

I have tried to no avail:

fdisk -> only shows loopback interface

gparted live cd -> only finds /dev/sr0 inteface (the cdrom itself)

changing sata mode in bios settings (from ahci to ide)

physically disconnect and reconnect the harddrive in the enclosure

I fear that the install has corrupted my hard drive in some way. Could this be possible or is there still some way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the drive was old and getting ready to crap out anyway I doubt if a failed install could destroy it.

You don't need to change anything in the bios if it was working before.  Change IDE back to ahci.

In your bios make sure you haven't inadvertently disabled your drive.  Make sure it still shows up in the boot order. Save and exit bios amd retry the install.

Comment: I have already tried that. While it shows in the boot order, it doens't actually boot. In a LiveCD or USB environment it also doens't show anything. For example when I try to install via a USB with Ubuntu the only devices it finds is itself. /dev/sda actually points to the USB itself and there isn't any other one.